# Restore main menu items in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, menu, lxde

Can someone post here /home/your_user/.config/menus/lxde-application.menu file?

I've got it rewritten and now my menu is broken.

Or if someone know how to restore main menu applet - feel free to answer
Thank you

Comment: I don't even have that file!!!

Comment: Did you try to find the above mentioned file from the live lubuntu installation media? You can copy that from there, if you find it there.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have guest account you should be able to log on as guest (or another account) and copy the file from there to your account.
2. Another possible solution:  I know that if you delete an application config file in your home folder and then restart, a new config file will be created and it is supposed to be the default file.  At least that worked for me.  I am not sure if that will apply to the entire main menu, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method to reset your main menu and bring the entire thing back:

Start - Run
pcmanfm
Go to: /usr/share/applications
Main Menu
Restore default menu
Close window
Reboot